# Passing data from Tableview to child of a tabbar controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a Tableview displaying data from a core DB.
When a row is selected I pass information to a view controller (vc) in func prepareForSugue.

Problem is the vc I pass this information to is a child of a Tab Bar controller, and by making a segue directly to the vc I bypass this Tab Bar controller, this in turn results in the absence of a tab bar in the vc.

My question is there anyway to pass data from a tableview to the fist child of a tab bar controller and ensure the Tab Bar hierarchy is maintained?

Any input appreciated.

Tableview prepare for segue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {


        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

        if(segue.identifier == "ItemDetailsSegue"){

            //initilise new vc and cast as history view controller
            var viewcontroller = segue.destinationViewController as History;

            // pass the caseNumber we got from didselectRow to History property / instance var

            println("Passing case Number to Hisory: \(caseNumberToPAsstoHistory)");

            viewcontroller.caseNumberSelected = caseNumberToPAsstoHistory;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can just segue to the tabbar instead of your custom view and let the tabbar show your view, but i think you already know that. Beyond that, you might be able to access the `selectedViewController` property of your tabBarController, might be set already. I don´t know if that works and can´t try it at the moment...

Comment: Thanks, if i sugue directly to Tab Bar how do i instantiate the tab controller in my tableview preparForSuugue and pass data to it in order to further pass the data to first vc child? Ivd added code to original question to make it clearer...

Comment: you should create a segue in the your storyboard between the controller containing the tableview and the one with the tab bar. Then you give that segue an identifier of your choice. In your code where you detect a select on the tableview you trigger the segue by calling `performSegueWithIdentifier` on `self`. you then should be able to access the tabBarController the same way you are currently doing it.

Comment: You then should able access the properts `selectedViewController` of that controller, as your viewcontroller type `History` and then set whatever you want. I am not 100% sure that works, but i think it should.

Answer (score 1):

After luk2302 advice I instantiated tabBar controllers first child from its array of view controllers and passed the data :

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {


        if(segue.identifier == "ItemDetailsSegue"){


            var tabBarCOntroller : UITabBarController = segue.destinationViewController as UITabBarController;

            var destinationViewController_History : History = tabBarCOntroller.viewControllers?.first as History;

// Set the case number selected property of History vc
            destinationViewController_History.caseNumberSelected = caseNumberToPAsstoHistory;



            println("Passing case Number to Hisory: \(caseNumberToPAsstoHistory)");


        }
    }
```

Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: thanks for answer it solved my first vc of the tabbar controller but when I try to nagivate second VC from the top VC but it is giving an error which tells VC cannot cast to UITabBarController

Comment: No problem glad it helped

Comment: I have 2 tabbar VCs I passed data to first tabbar VC and but I can't pass data to 2 with same approach :(

Comment: Can you select the UITabbatconyrollers second VC or pass data from the first VC to the 2nd?

Comment: i have tableview which holds buses' name,number I just navigate from each cell to tabbar

Comment: first VC of the tab bar show routes of the bus and second shows hours

Comment: I just want to pass bus data from table view cell to both VCs

Comment: i mean my purpose is not send data from first VC to second I just want to pass common bus data from tableview cell to tabbar's VCs

Comment: So Is data sourced from the tableview Row or core data ? You could try access data in your 2nd VC by casting the second child of tabbarcontroller with a prepareForsegue call or pass all data to the first VC from table view row (because we know this is possible form example above), make data visible globally in first VC or pass data directly to the 2nd VC ptepareForSegue call form the first VC...

Comment: data source is realm database but I don't want to pass data from first to second i just want to pass from cell to 1 and 2 VCs

Comment: Did u try cast your 2nd VC from 2nd child of tabbarcontroller?

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: Not in front of Xcode now but try call second child of tabbarcontroller : var tabBarCOntroller : UITabBarController = segue.destinationViewController as UITabBarController;              var destinationViewController : yourVC = tabBarCOntroller.viewControllers?.second as yourVC;

Comment: there is only .last extension but it couldn't solve :(